# Is it ok charge a 4S1P(16.8v) 18650 with 24v@0.5A?

Tags: voltage

I have the vacuum cleaner Ilife V7s pro. And I opened the battery pack, it was a 4S1P batteries: 18650 2600mah.

However the charger adapter output is: 24v 0.5.

With my little knowledge, 24v will be: 24 / 4 batteries = 6v instead of a maximum of 4.2v for each cell, isn't it wrong, bad or dangerous?

The pack has a PCM with it. Does pcm reduce a higher voltage to what it needs? 
[image]

This is the model of Vacuum cleaner:

https://www.ebay.com/itm/ILIFE-V7s-PLUS-Robotic-Vacuum-Cleaner-Robot-Dry-Wet-Cleaning-Brand-New/392658291952?hash=item5b6c420cf0:g:WPMAAOSwQF5eLsDY

And this is the adapter charger:

https://www.ebay.com/itm/Vacuum-Cleaner-Adapter-Charger-For-ILife-V7s-pro-V7-V7s-EU-24V-0-5A/323950604868?hash=item4b6cf5f244:g:WrEAAOSw12Nc21lV

Thanks a lot.

Comment: What do you mean with PCM here? And no, the input voltage is not directly applied to batteries, that PCB is the charger.

Comment: PCM = Protecting circuit module or protecting circuit module.

Comment: Also, why not have an adapter with 16.8v or 17v instead of 24v? Is there any advantage for it?

Comment: powering a 4S battery charger with 24v is just fine, charging a 4S battery with it directly is not.

Comment: 16.8v or 17v will have too little headroom for the charger to charge the batteries. 24v power supplies are commonly available with suitable ratings, no need to produce a custom power supply.

Comment: The PCB you show looks like it contains more than only battery protection. My guess is that it (also) contains a **battery charging circuit**. I conclude this from the presence of RS2 (current sense resistor) and Q3, Q4 which look like MOSFETs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The power supply is not the charger, and the 24V from the power supply is not directly connected to the battery. The charger PCB charges the batteries with suitable charging curve. The charger PCB is designed to operate with a 24V power supply.

Comment: Thank you guys. I guess the "extra volts" will be dissipated in heat.

Comment: Impossible to know just from looking at those photos. Dissipating extra volts as heat would be just wasting electricity. Charging circuits can also use switch-mode converters that are highly efficient at converting voltages.